Finding connected subgraph of the connected graph
I'm facing a problem where I need to identify connected subgraphs of a simple and connected graph G. Generally, I need to find all connected subgraphs of fixed size n, which satisfy certain constraints (such as vertex $v_k$ has to be included or vertex $v_l$ has to be excluded from subgraphs). Unfortunately, the only algorithm I could think of is to generate all subgraphs (given constraints) and check whether they are connected. This does not sound optimal, hence I'm reaching out to you. Has anyone faced such a similar problem and knows the algorithm that could help?
To set some ground in what realm of numbers do we operate, Graph G, before applying constraints, has around 50 nodes, and I'm looking to enumerate subgraphs of size 30.
Best regards
Szymon

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75727217/fast-way-to-find-all-connected-subgraphs-of-given-size-in-python/75751315#75751315

How many constraints do you expect to have, and is there any more information about the constraints (e.g. do the "must-include" nodes already form a connected subgraph)? Also, roughly how many edges will G have?

So, In general, the graph will have between 52 and 60 nodes. There will be, at most, 3 times as many edges as nodes (usually closer to 1.5 times more, actually, except for some extreme cases). The set of "must-include" constraints is not already a connected graph. It is simply a list of nodes that the valid answer must include. That "must-include" constraint, might be skipped if it does not help to optimize the solution. As for must-exclude nodes, there will usually be between 10 to 15 of them each time.

The must-exclude nodes are not a big deal since you can just pretend they aren't there, and you just have a smaller graph. (That is less true if you are doing many queries on the same graph but with different must-exclude constraints.) The number of must-include constraints is much more significant.

There will be at least 1 must-include constraint, as it's a kinda tree-like graph (although it can have cycles, so not a graph-theory tree), and it has to be built from the root. As for the upper bound, I'd expect at most 6, although the number can be lowered depending on the computation overhead

@kaya3 Would you be able to help? I do not mean to hasten you in any way; I appreciate the immense help provided so far. Simply would like to know if you have an idea and if I should patiently wait or if it is a lost cause and I should re-consider my ideas and give up on must-include nodes.

If there is only one must-include constraint, or otherwise the must-include constraints happen to be connected already by chance, then the algorithm in the linked question can be adapted. Otherwise it might be a good idea to start by finding the ways to connect the must-include vertices, then expand those to subgraphs of the required size; but this could produce duplicate subgraphs. It's not obvious if duplicate subgraphs can be prevented at that stage, or if not, if this is really faster than a search which has to check the result is connected but doesn't revisit duplicate subgraphs.

Finding the different ways to connect the vertices is closely related to the Steiner tree problem in graphs. I don't have any more ideas than that.

@kaya3 Thank you very much for this! I think I will start by adjusting the algorithm to require only connected "must-include" nodes which start from the root and then explore other possibilities after the first version is working. Appreciate all your help
